# Having trouble saving a nested form detail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models here, an owner and note. On the owner form at the bottom I have a nested form for a text area to store a note.
It works perfectly for new, but on edit if there is no note it won't save the relationship between the note and the current_user. it saves the note, but not the user_id who recorded the note.

Here is what my controller looks like

Thanks for any help in advance, or at least for looking :)

owner.rb

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:note_text].blank? }

end
```

owners_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  unless @owner.notes.present?   
    @owner.notes.build
  end
end

def update
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.notes.each do |n|
    if n.created_by_id == nil
      n.created_by_id = current_user
    else
      n.updated_by_id = current_user
    end
  end
  respond_to do |f|
    if @owner.update_attributes(params[:owner])
      f.html { redirect_to @owner, notice: 'Owner successfully updated.' }
      f.json { head :ok }
    else
      f.html { render action: "edit" }
      f.json { render json: @owner.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

oh and my note.rb model

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :pet
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by_id"
  belongs_to :updated_by, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

`@owner.update_attributes(params[:owner])` is where notes come into existence in the update method, but it takes place *after* you do `@owner.notes.each` so of course, the block of code redarding the current user does not get run.